# Has JavaFX a similar mechanism like SWT's setRedraw()?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, swt

Is there an equivalent to SWT's `Control.setRedraw(false)` in JavaFX?

I would like to

1. disable UI paint events dispatching for a specific scene node (in SWT this can be done with `Control.setRedraw(false)`)
2. modify/add "lots of" DOM nodes (using the `WebView`)
3. instruct JavaFX to flush all pending paint events for that scene node

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No - JavaFX has no setRedraw() to queue drawings - but you are free to construct the Node hierarchy in a detached mode and then attach the whole graph-structure at once (most nodes if not attached to the SG can be used in a none-ui thread as well - unfortunately webview is one of the exceptions!)

Comment: When using JavaFX's SWT integration, namely FXCanvas, and calling FXCanvas.setRedraw(false) seems to drop all paint events which I think could be used for this case. Am I right?

Comment: If i understand FXCanvas correct what it does is to let JavaFX render into an offscreen buffer, makes a snapshot and transfers that back to SWT and draws the pixels on the SWT-Canvas. So I guess you could get some performance from doing the setRedraw() on SWT-Canvas - the JavaFX offscreen UI will update in between whenever you modify a node there so this performance loss would still be there